# Plot 2D piecewise constant in matlab in a finite elements mesh

Tags: finite-element, matlab, discontinuous-galerkin, octave

I need to generate a discontinuous plot (piecewise in each triangle) in matlab, something like:

[image: Discontinuous plot, solution of finite elements method]

This plot is from http://www.alecjacobson.com/weblog/?p=3616, but I don't understand how generate it.

---

I have two matrices corresponding to a triangular mesh of a domain (typical of finite elements method, that is, no overlaped triangles, the union of all triangles is equal to the domain...):

```
coord=[x1,y1;x2,y2;...;xnod,ynod]      % vertices of the mesh
ele  =[n1,n2,n3;n1,n2,n3;...;n1,n2,n3] % mesh conectivity
```

For example:

```
coord(1,:)=[x1,y1] are the coordinates of vertex 1 of the mesh (vertex of some triangle)
coord(2,:)=[x2,y2] are the coordinates of vertex 2 of the mesh (vertex of some triangle)
etc,


ele(1,:)=[n1,n2,n3] is the number of the vertices of triangle 1
ele(2,:)=[n1,n2,n3] is the number of the vertices of triangle 2
etc.
```

This way, for example,

```
coord(ele(4,:),:)=[x1,y1;x2,y2;x3,y3]
```

are the coordinates (x1,y1), (x2,y2) and (x3,y3) of the vertices of triangle 4.

**The solution that I need to plot is a vector "u"** which size is the number of triangles of the mesh (=number of rows of "elem"), because this solution is **one constant** over each triangle.

**How can I plot this discontinuous solution?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use typically the following approach. The idea is to make a new mesh where every vertex is duplicated so that each triangle has its own copy. Then you can use standard *trisurf* command to the resulting mesh structure.

```
p=coord';
t=ele';
x=p(1,:);
y=p(2,:);
P=[x(t(:));y(t(:))];
T=reshape(1:size(P,2),[3 size(P,2)/3]);
% create random u for testing
u=rand(size(P,2)/3,1);
tmp=[u';u';u'];
trisurf(T',P(1,:),P(2,:),tmp(:))
```

[image]

If you have PDE toolbox there is also a built in command for this called *pdesurf*.