# Plot 2D piecewise function in MATLAB

Tags: finite-element, matlab

I'm trying to use this method [Plot 2D piecewise constant in matlab in a finite elements mesh](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/26739/plot-2d-piecewise-constant-in-matlab-in-a-finite-elements-mesh) for my data. However, I have problems with the values of n1, n2 and n3. I guess this is why it doesn't show a figure for what I have written.

What values would be appropriate for n1, n2, n3?

Comment: If you have a mesh of triangles $T_1 = (P_{i_1}, P_{j_1}, P_{k_1})$, $T_2 = (P_{i_2}, P_{j_2}, P_{k_2})$ and so on, you fill the matrix N with those indices: $N = [i_1, j_1, k_1 ; i_2, j_2, k_2; ...]$ with a different line for each triangle.

Comment: @Sardine So you mean that n1, n2, n3 are the indices of the triangles?

Comment: Maybe that's what you mean, but to be pedantic, they are the indices of the vertices in the triangles, not of the triangles. Imagine you have 4 points forming two triangles: triangle 1 is points 2, 3, 1 and triangle 2 is points 1, 4, 2. Then the matrix is [2 3 1; 1 4 2].

Comment: @Sardine You're right! I finally got it! Thank you!